# Using password_hash and password_verify, why isn't the password in the database hashed?

Tags: php, mysql

I guess the title is pretty self explanatory. I am using the password_hash function in my login.php. When I take a look in the database, I see the password is not hashed. Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? Here is my piece of code (safe_post_value is my own function to escape the string):

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $safe_username = safe_post_value($username);
    $safe_password = safe_post_value($password);
    $hashed_password = password_hash($safe_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $verified_password = password_verify($password, $hashed_password);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE '$safe_username' = `username`";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
        if ($verified_password){
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                printf("%s, %s\n", $row['username'], $row['password']);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $message = "error";
        echo $message;
    }
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="gebruikersnaam">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="wachtwoord">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="verstuur">
</form>
```

So, to be clear: this code is working, but I was just wondering if it's normal that the password is not hashed in the database.

Comment: The password should be hashed in the database, but all you're doing here is playing with the password that the user has entered and checking it as a plaintext value.... where's your code for setting the user's password and then storing it in the database?

Comment: You haven't showed us the code that puts it in the database.

Comment: can you show the code that is inserting the password?

Comment: You do not use password on the query, that said safe_post_value isn't a php function, maybe it returns nothing?

Comment: Warning: `WHERE '$safe_username' = username"` <== injection vulnerability. Oh, and the password probably isn't hashed, because you're not storing the hash in the DB, but the actual password.

Comment: I'm sorry, perhaps a stupid question. I didn't have code to put things in the database (e.g. a register.php), I had put it in myself. That would explain why it won't work :) Thanks for the comments!

Comment: safe_post_value might strip out the password so you won't have a match, either strip both password, or leave them out.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem why is there injection vulnerability? I used mysqli_real_escape_string on the username and the password. It's in my functions.php in the function safe_post_value(). Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @julia: prepared statements are just better than manual escaping + [read the big caution box on the man pages](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem thanks for your answer. It's a bit too complicated for me now but I'll definitely use it in the future. What I'm doing now is just for testing purposes so it doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($safe_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$verified_password = password_verify($password, $hashed_password);
```

You generate $safe_password from $password so it will be certainly same.
And your query must be like

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ".$safe_username." and password = ".$safe_password"
```